# Alamofire.upload with query parameters

Tags: alamofire

I'm using `Alamofire.upload` to upload an image as a `.POST` multipart to my server. But my server always gets parameters only as a query string, and use multipart only for a file data. So in my request I also need to put some parameters to URL, but it seems `Alamofire.upload` have't a variant with parameters argument.

```
Alamofire.upload(
    .POST,
    "https://httpbin.org/post?user=\(userId)&photo=\(photoTitle)",
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: unicornImageURL, name: "unicorn")
    },
    encodingCompletion: nil
)
```

For now I just put all parameters by myself directly forming request-string: `"https://httpbin.org/post?user=\(userId)&photo=\(photoTitle)"`. 
Is there a better way to pass query parameters to `Alamofire.upload`?

Comment: Having the same problem, but apparently it's not a hot topic

Comment: @Mayerz, I just posted some workaround, which I am using for now.

Comment: thanks man! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

What can do things better is `Alamofire.ParameterEncoding`, but it will need some workaround with requests.

```
    var req: NSMutableURLRequest?
    (req!, _) = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(
        NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://httpbin.org")!),
        parameters: ["user": userId, "photo": photoTitle]
    )

    Alamofire.upload(
        .POST,
        req!.URLString,
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: unicornImageURL, name: "unicorn")
        },
        encodingCompletion: nil
    )
```